# requestAnimationFrame on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, animation, canvas

Is it possible to call requestAnimationFrame on an iPhone (iOS 5.1)? As far as I've been able to figure out, the mobile Safari simply doesn't this method, with or without vendor prefix.

Comment: I usually play all of my demos and animations with mobile Safari on the iPad and they all run on requestAnimFrame. No problems at all: it just lags due to the poor hw of the device, but the animation works.

Comment: btw, requestAnimFrame is not supported the same way across all browsers. You should use this shim from Paul Irish, the one which I used and works on the iPad: http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Comment: uhh, that _is_ requestAnimFrame, Paul Irish just updated it to include *Eric Möller*'s shim /nitpicking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not look like it does. Here is a link to a set of screenshots I took of a jsfiddle I wrote.

**Screenshot link**
http://crossbrowsertesting.com/users/34762/screenshots/z7e91b18ffb5e81e5079/public

**jsfiddle link**
http://jsfiddle.net/fpmeh/

On the 5.1 IOS screenshot you will see the text is set to nothing in the jsfiddle. On newer browsers from that same text is set to one of the different available methods.

Answer (score 2):

This is fully supported from iOS 7  onwards.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=requestanimationframe